# During migration to Webpack 2 I encounter a babel loader error

Tags: webpack

I have the following webpack configuration for js loader:

```
   module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
                "plugins": ['transform-runtime']
            }
        },
```

It works, but when I try to change **loaders** to **rules** it doesn't work and I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: D:\src\index.js Unexpected token (16:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| render(
|     <Router history={browserHistory}>
|         <Route path='/' component={App}>
|             <IndexRoute component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax for `rules` is not the same as the syntax for `loaders`.](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) It should look something like this in your case:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
                plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```